# How to get rows In each Group with minimum order group and special name in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have a table similar this

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test](
    [Name] [NCHAR](10) NULL,
    [GroupId] [INT] NULL,
    [GroupOrder] [INT] NULL
    )
```

and below values

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('A',1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('A-1',1,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('B',2,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('B',2,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('B-1',2,3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('C',3,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('C-1',3,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('C-1',3,3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('D',4,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('D',4,2)
```

i need output like this: rows In each Group with minimum order group and name field contain "-1"

```
    Name    GroupId GroupOrder
    A-1         1   2
    C-1         3   2
    B-1         2   3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
Select * from 
(
select *,Row_Number() Over(Partition by GroupId Order by GroupOrder asc) as rn
From yourtable 
Where Name like '%-1%' 
) a
Where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `charindex`, `top 1 with ties`, and `row_number`

```
select Top (1) with ties
       * 
from Test t
where charindex('-1', t.Name ) > 0
order by row_number() over(partition by t.GroupId order by t.GroupOrder)
```

Demo link: http://rextester.com/RBBKX12749

Comment: `partition by GroupId` most probably.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function

```
Select * from 
(
select *,Row_Number() Over(Partition by Name Order by GroupOrder asc) as rn
From yourtable 
Where rtrim(Name) like '[A-Z]-1'  
) a
Where rn = 1
```

If the `Name` should end with `-1` then use `Where Name like '%-1'`. If `Name` just contains `-1` then `Where Name like '%-1%'`

Answer (score 1):

```
  CREATE TABLE [dbo].[#Test](
    [Name] [NCHAR](10) NULL,
    [GroupId] [INT] NULL,
    [GroupOrder] [INT] NULL
    )


INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('A',1,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('A-1',1,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('B',2,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('B',2,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('B-1',2,3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('C',3,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('C-1',3,2)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('C-1',3,3)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('D',4,1)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[#Test]([Name],[GroupId],[GroupOrder]) VALUES ('D',4,2)

select * from #Test

 Select * from 
(
select *,Row_Number() Over(Partition by Name Order by GroupOrder asc) as rn
From #Test 
Where Name like '%[-1]%'
) a
Where rn = 1
ORDER BY GroupOrder
```

OUTPUT

```
Name    GroupId GroupOrder  
A-1         1   2   
B-1         2   3    
C-1         3   2
```